# Generate tests skeleton when creating a gem

Tags: ruby, bundler

Is there a tool for creating Ruby gem which automatically generate not only project file structure, but also tests file structure (with default ruby assert tests or rspec)?

Comment: For example, Rails creates projects with tests skeleton already in. But be aware that automated test generation is to be used only by those, who are familiar with ther "manual" generation, otherwise it'll make one dumb.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky, I did this manually several times, now I'm looking for the way to automate this process. I know that Rails have this functionality, but I don't need this for Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at `hoe`, which allows you to write your own project templates in `erb`, amongst other goodies. See http://docs.seattlerb.org/hoe/

Personally I have found, despite looking for something like this initially, that `bundle gem <gemname>` and a quick reference to an earlier project is not all that much work in practice, considering the number of gems I have written (about 7, though only one is published).  Boris Stitnicky's comment rings true for me as well - understanding why a particular structure works, and building it from scratch at least a couple of times is worth the time invested in gaining Ruby knowledge.

However, if my day job project involved creating many in-house gems, I'd probably be using `hoe`, or a similar tool to get them started consistently.